# What is the view of prototype theory regarding features?

Tags: semantics, meaning, cognitive-linguistics, prototype-theory

For example, the most prototypical exemplars of bird is `robin`, the least ones are `ostrich` or `penguin`. But since it rejects the classical theory (aka the necessary and sufficient conditions), I think it should talk about conditions instead of exemplars to avoid comparing apple with orange. So for example, `fly`, `animal`, and `eating worm` are the most prototypical conditions, and `running fast` or `living in Antarctica` are less prototypical.

So why doesn't the prototype theory talk about features? I agree that the theory is meant to describe the reality that regular thinking isn't about features or boundaries, but being able to discuss with features is also convenient as well.

Advantages of using features can be seen in polysemy, meaning shift, or metaphor:

- In polysemy there is a basic sense that is frequently used than others. ([A course in Cognitive Linguistics: Polysemy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEWTCzK_hUU))
- In 1980s, most people in the United States would consider a "family" consisted a legally married heterosexual couple and a child. Without a child they are just a couple, and without a legally marriage they just cohabit. Now the definition/understanding/perception/attitude is more flexible.
- When we say an argument is like a war, we don't think much about typical arguments, but about features of `argument` and `war`. Only with features that we can map from the source domain to the target; a list of exemplars of argument is hard to map to a list of exemplars of war. Comparing a fiery debate between John and Mary with World War 2 sounds odd.
  [image]

Comment: Because the definition is provided by similarity to the exemplar. Any features that may occur to one are valid, but not "defining" -- definition by distinctive features comes much later, if ever, and it's not necessary in any event.

Comment: I think I can understand that. Can you elaborate more? Would the prototype theory be able to applied to defining features/conditions?

Comment: One can recognize features from a prototype, but one is never sure whether they're defining. Robins can fly, but some birds can't. Robins have feathers and two feet, but is that defining? They also have red breasts and yellow beaks. And then there are categories that don't have a central prototype. Anyway, why worry about features? They're just stick-figures of the real prototype.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I just update the question to address why using features is better

Comment: No. Go read Lakoff and Johnson instead before you start talking about metaphors.

Comment: I haven't read them, but have watched Martin Hilpert's [A course in Cognitive Linguistics: Metaphor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0BYLpwSM6E&t=6s) and read Gentner's [structure-mapping theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure-mapping_theory). Is that enough?

Comment: "When we say an argument is like a war, we don't think much about typical arguments, but about features of argument and war." Citation needed. The whole point of Prototype Theory is that regular thinking *isn't* about features, or boundaries, or whatever. We normally categorise by similarity to the exemplars/prototypes. And your examples definitely don't show why features are *better*.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have added more points in the question. Can you check that?

Comment: Don't make edits to bump your question. If you want to encourage answers you can make a bounty instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's just extrinsic motivation, and I doubt it's effective, given the lack of interest on this. Do you know how to make the question **intrinsically interesting**? What else I need to learn more? Thanks

Comment: I guess if you could find research suggesting empirical evidence for feature analysis rather than it just being a good framework for analysis?